# Triple Monitor Setup Problem (specifc, could not find an answer)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xrandr

Despite my sincerest efforts to avoid asking a question that thousands of others have had similar issues -- alas, I am not skilled enough in Linux to diagnose this myself and no other solution attempt has worked.

I'm trying to run a triple monitor setup, two screens work just fine off the GTX 760 however the other monitor (attached to an GTX 950) can be enabled but displays a black background and it allows me to move the mouse over onto the screen but displays the cursor as an X.

Using NVidia's proprietary drivers. Another important detail, NVidia's config app allows me to configure the monitor (all 3) however xrandr only shows the two monitors attached to the 760.

Alas, I am lost.